# Cannot install Ruby on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, cpanel

I just cannot install Ruby on my CentOS (which is also hosting a cPanel).

sudo yum install ruby ruby-devel ruby-irb ruby-rdoc ruby-ri

---

audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
- updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
- addons: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
- extras: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net

base                                                     | 1.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  |  951 B     00:00
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00
extras                                                   | 1.1 kB     00:00

Excluding Packages in global exclude list

Finished

Setting up Install Process

Parsing package install arguments

No package ruby available.

No package ruby-devel available.

No package ruby-irb available.

No package ruby-rdoc available.

No package ruby-ri available.

Nothing to do

---

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ruby **1.8.6** I had to add another repository.

Create /etc/yum.repos.d/ruby.repo and add the following:

```
[ruby]
name=ruby
baseurl=http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=0
```

Then

```
yum --enablerepo=ruby install ruby
```

From [www.centos.org forums](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=11821).

Don't bother installing rubygems this way, it's obsolete.

Comment: yum --enablerepo=ruby install ruby

Comment: Broken link: http://repo.premiumhelp.eu/ruby/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"

Answer (score 11):

The recommended way to install ruby on a cPanel/WHM server is to run the script /scripts/installruby as root. Or you could remove ruby from the exclude list at your own risk.

More info at:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/RubyonRails/InstallingRuby

Comment: Please paste the commands. If the link is deprecated the answer is useless.

Answer (score 5):

CPanel/WHM puts the ruby packages the exclude list. If you verify your `/etc/yum.conf` file, you will probably see a line similar to:

```
exclude= (...) ruby* (...)
```

The recommended way to install ruby on a cPanel/WHM server is to run the script `/scripts/installruby` as root. Or you could remove ruby from the exclude list at your own risk.

More info at:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/RubyonRails/InstallingRuby

Answer (score 1):

Better Way Go to Software section in WHM and then go to 'modules' then select Ruby Gems.....
It would ask you to install and continue!(select that)

It would be a very long process (in terms of text)
A portion of text i got in the installation process:-

```
RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /usr/bin/gem

Removing source directory /home/cprubygemsbuild
gem system update ...
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.24
Updating RubyGems to 1.8.24
Installing RubyGems 1.8.24
RubyGems 1.8.24 installed

== 1.8.24 / 2012-04-27

* 1 bug fix:

  * Install the .pem files properly. Fixes #320
  * Remove OpenSSL dependency from the http code path


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /usr/bin/gem

gem system update complete.

Installing rails...
```

I found this method just now

Comment: Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
Successfully installed activesupport-2.3.14
Successfully installed activerecord-2.3.14
Successfully installed rack-1.1.3
Successfully installed actionpack-2.3.14
Successfully installed actionmailer-2.3.14
Successfully installed activeresource-2.3.14
Successfully installed rails-2.3.14

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found was to install everything manually

[manual install guide](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/installation/linux)