# Installing ruby on CentOS

Tags: ruby, centos

Hai.

I am trying to install [What's Next GTD](http://whatsnextapp.com/) on my CentOS machine. The app requires sqlite3-ruby installed. So i tried installing ruby first. Unfortunately, the yum installation says : "No package ruby available". Yes i know there are similar topics which already discussed this. One of them was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346478/cannot-install-ruby-on-centos). So i tried what was discussed back then. Still, i got the same output : "No package ruby available".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you are looking for a programming solution to this?

Comment: I knew it's kind of weird posting such a question here. But my link above shows that similar question exists. Based on that, i post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [download Ruby source code](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and compile it

Answer (score 6):

## INSTALLING RUBY ON RAILS:

1) Install Ruby

See:
http://rubyonrails.org/down

wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.2-p136
./configure --with-openssl-dir=/usr/lib/openssl
make
sudo make install

2) Install ruby gems
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/74140/rubygems-1.5.0.tgz
tar -zxvf rubygems-1.5.0.tgz
cd rubygems-1.5.0
sudo ruby setup.rb config
sudo ruby setup.rb setup
sudo ruby setup.rb install

3) Install Rails:
sudo gem install --version '2.2.3' rails --include-dependencies

4) Install Mongrel
sudo gem install mongrel mongrel_cluster

Answer (score 1):

Install Ruby 2.1.2

```
sudo wget http://cache.ruby­lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby­2.1.2.tar.gz
sudo tar xvfvz ruby­2.1.2.tar.gz
sudo rm ruby­2.1.2.tar.gz
cd ruby­2.1.2
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```